# Combining Beautiful Soup find_all list into one element

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have created a script that parses through emails on a weekly basis looking for tables within specific emails.  I know that I want things that are within a table tag with a specific class name.  The goal then is to take those tables, essentially concat them with a 
 tag in between, and put into another email to automatically send every week.

What I have so far is the actual email scraping, the sending of the email at the end, but I just don't know how to combine the results of a find_all into one element.  I'm obviously open to different approaches, which is why I posed the question as thus.

What I have for code is this:

```
def parse_messages(enhance_str):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(enhance_str, 'html.parser')
    table = soup.find_all('table', {'class': 'MsoNormalTable'})
    return table
```

which gives me a list-like object (I know find_all sub classes list), but any list methods I know don't work with this object.  I thought I could just do something like

```
'<br/>'.join(table)
```

but this throws an attribute error.

I'm sure there is a simple answer, but I can't see it.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT:  As a clarifcation, I was just trying to preserve the html structure of these tables so I can just pop them into a new email and send them as is.  The solution below works for me, so I'm marking it as the accepted answer.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The elements in the output list of `soup.find_all` are `bs4.element.Tag` objects, not some objects you can join together as-is to make a string.

I'm not sure what you're upto but if you want to make them all a single `str`, you can iterate over the `Tag`s, call `str` on them to get the string representation and then `join`:

```
'<br/>'.join([str(tag) for tag in table])
```